# Creating placement grid in Unity

Tags: unity, c#, grid

I'm fairly new to C# and Unity, so I don't really know much about it.

I want to create an RTS like game where you have a huge grid that the whole world is placed on. Then you can place houses, walls etc on the tiles just like a lot other RTS games (i.e. Age of Empires, Stronghold Series etc).

How would I go about this in Unity? I could imagine having some Terrain/World manager that handles all the models and objects that you can interact with etc. And probably a lot of prefabs too with the different items, soldiers and so.

So if anyone have any smart way of doing this or maybe a link to a tutorial explaining, then the help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You don't exactly need a grid actually. If you don't need to get information back from tile, you can create a fake tile illusion by "snapping" objects to certain floating points.

For instance, say, you want to have a grid that has placement points on 0, 1, 2, 3 and 4. 
 Then when the object is at 0.3f, you round it to 0; 
 and when it is at 0.7f, you round it to 1 (etc.).

This way you will create a snapping effect that gives illusion of a grid.